# Get available display resolution list

Tags: delphi

Is it possible to get resolution list like in Display preferences? See attached image. I'm using Delphi XE3

I can enum DeviceModeList (source: http://www.delphifeeds.com/go/s/96231)

```
var
   cnt : Integer;
   DevMode : TDevMode;
 begin
   cnt := 0;
   while EnumDisplaySettings(nil,cnt,DevMode) do
   begin
     with Devmode do
      ListBox1.Items.Add(Format('%dx%d %d Colors', [dmPelsWidth,dmPelsHeight,Int64(1) shl dmBitsperPel])) ;
     Inc(cnt) ;
   end;
 end;
```

First problem:

There are resulution I can not set using windows display preferences. Of course I can cut this < 800x600 - But this is a poor idea :)

Next problem:

There is no information on whether the resolution is greyed out (like in display preferences)

I will be grateful for any help in resolving these two problems.

Best regards!

[image: Display preferences]

Comment: Windows DWM uses DirectX, so I guess this combo box is populated by DirectX method ([IDXGIOutput1::GetDisplayModeList1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/desktop/hh404606(v=vs.85).aspx) without [DXGI_ENUM_MODES_SCALING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/desktop/cc308060(v=vs.85).aspx) maybe?).

Comment: Thank you for tip. I will try to check it today